# how to find out the current date time stamp in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, timestamp, midp

How can I get the time stamp for current date in j2me code?

I want to convert the current date into timestamp something like this we do in Java SE :

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Comment: You've kinda moved the goalposts... My answer shows how to format time, you could include that in a method called "timeStamp(Date date)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public class DateAndTime extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{
  private Display disp;
  private Date d;
  private DateField currentDate;
  private Form form;
  private int index;

  public DateAndTime(){
    form = new Form("Data and Time");
    d = new Date();
    currentDate = new DateField("", DateField.DATE_TIME);
    currentDate.setDate(d);
  }

  public void startApp(){
    index = form.append(currentDate);
    disp = Display.getDisplay(this);
    disp.setCurrent(form);
  }

}
```

This link provide complete tutorial: [current-date-time](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/current-date-time.shtml)

Hope this helps.

**Edit:-**

try something like this:

```
new Date().getTime();
//------- OR
long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date dt = new Date(dtMili);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dt);
cal.getTime(); //-------- This will give you the timestamp.
```

Comment: @Mikaveli: yes imports are required.

Answer (score 2):

`new java.util.Date();`

- [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html)

Comment: hey I want to convert the current date into timestamp something like this we do in java...

Comment: what exactly you mean by timestamp garima

Comment: I want to compare to time periods so using the date directly is not helping..so needed the time stamp for that date

Comment: `new java.util.Date().getTime()` will return you long , current millis then you can easily compare  using `>` or `<`

Comment: yup.. that would do the thing... tx

Comment: This is not fair Garima. You got answer from here and you accepted some other. make it clear

Answer (score 1):

It use `java.util package`

see this link

http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/current-date-time.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Time = Unix timestamp format. I added 64800 second to the time so it would be converted to Mountain Standard Time.

```
*timestamp 24 * 60 * 60

.getTime()//milliseconds 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

private DateField dateField1; ///////////////////////

dateField1= new DateField("Date:", DateField.DATE); f.append(dateField1);

Date d = new Date(); dateField1.setDate(d);

String TimeSeg = String.valueOf(((dateField1.getDate().getTime()/1000)+64800));
```